# Get list (sorted by shortest) of paths of a graph/network (directed, weighted, cyclic)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a network/graph in "json graph format" (https://github.com/jsongraph/json-graph-specification). I have an initial node/vertex (lets call it "0"). I need a ranked list (sorted by path-length, begin with shortest) of paths going from 0 to ONE of the nodes in the box (5,7,8,9) and back to 0. I hope that explains it well enough. A real life example would be a group of children running to a wall and back. I want to find the shortest way to this wall and back. Note that edges can have a different length on the way back.
A solution is php is prefered. Javscript is also good.

[image: graph]

Comment: Can you show any research or code that you have tried so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
There is no point in starting to code when you don´t know how to address the problem.

Comment: SO is more aimed at helping solve coding problems, if you have problems when you have started coding then this is more suitable a question for here (IMHO).

Comment: Possibly this will help you. Read it, write some code, and if you are stuck, update your question and add some code so we can see what you have tried. https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2018/02/06/binary-search-trees-in-php/